# SUM using CASE WHEN SELECT

Tags: sql, t-sql

How can I re-write this query so that it doesn't trigger the following error:

*"Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."*

```
SELECT
    employees.loc_id
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN 
                pos IN (SELECT DISTINCT pos FROM lookup WHERE lbl='Staff') 
            AND 
                loc IN (SELECT DISTINCT loc FROM lookup WHERE lbl='Staff')
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
        END) AS 'Staff Site 1'
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN 
                pos IN (SELECT DISTINCT pos FROM table WHERE lbl='Staff') 
            AND 
                loc IN (SELECT DISTINCT loc FROM table WHERE lbl='Staff')
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
        END) AS 'Staff Site 2'

FROM table GROUP BY table.key_id ORDER BY key_id
```

So apparently I cannot put a `SELECT` statement within `SUM`? How can I make sure I'm only summing for the cases described in the above code?

`pos` determines the type of position. `loc` determines at what site (location). The lookup table is structured like this:

```
pos  | loc  | lbl
123  | XYZ  | Staff Site 1
456  | XYZ  | Staff Site 1
987  | XYZ  | Supervisor Site 1
123  | ABC  | Staff Site 2
123  | JKL  | Staff Site 3
123  | OPQ  | Staff Site 4
456  | OPQ  | Staff Site 4
345  | OPQ  | Staff Site 4
```

This lookup table simply determines the label associated with a position at a specific location.

There is an employee table and each employee is assigned a pos#.

So I wanted my query to select all the `loc_id` (location id) from the employee table, and for each `loc_id`, sum each respective entry in the lookup table

So if I had 30 employees with `loc_id=XYZ` with `pos=123` and 20 employees with `loc_id=XYZ` with `pos=456`, the output would be

```
loc_id | Staff Site 1
XYZ    | 50
```

Thanks in advance, and I hope this was not too confusing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without going into techniques to get around being able to SELECT inside an aggregate function.  Let's step back and rethink your query all together.  You are trying to solve it by aggregating the Lookup table but the aggregation is really on the Employee table with a join from the lookup table.

It also appears that you are trying to do conditional aggregation to PIVOT your result.  But in either event if you do the following you will get the result you specify if you do the following:

```
SELECT
    l.loc
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT e.Id) as EmployeesAtStaffSite1
FROM
    Lookup l
    INNER JOIN Employees e
    ON e.loc = l.loc
    AND e.pos = l.pos
WHERE
    l.lbl = 'Staff Site 1'
GROUP BY
    l.loc
```

Also note that if you change INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN you can get 0 count for any locations that are staff site 1 that there are no employees assigned.

Comment: I suspect that this returns a result that OP is wanting to return, but it's difficult to determine the exact specification. +10 for "let's remove the fingers from the keyboard, slowly back away, and *think* about what we're trying to achieve, and how to explain it..."

Comment: brilliant Matt. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The outer query references a table name `table`, but the column in the SELECT list is qualified with `employees.`. The query does a `GROUP BY table.key_id`, but the column returned in the SELECT list a column named `loc_id`. Both of the subqueries are looking for `lbl` match to literal 'Staff', the first set looking table named `lookup`.  We don't see any example rows in the `lookup` table where that condition will evaluate to true. In the second set, the subquery is referencing a different table (unfortunately named) `table`.

It's hard to tell what you are actually trying to accomplish with that query.

Confusingly, the last part of the question suggests that you want a resultset with two columns, distinct values of `loc_id` from the employee table.  And some sort of aggregate column containing a count of rows that satisfy some set of criteria...

```
 loc_id  Staff Site 1
 ------  ------------ 
 XYZ               50
```

Let's backup a few steps.

It looks like you are wanting to look at all rows in the `employee` table, and you are only concerned with three or four columns in the table. This is the set of rows and columns you want to analyze. (It's not clear whether you are needing to reference a column named `lbl` from the `table` table. The one set of subqueries that reference `table` instead of `lookup` make it look like that's the case.

So, starting with the set of rows you want the query to look at ...

```
 SELECT e.loc_id
      , e.pos
      , e.loc
   FROM employee e
```

From that, you want to get distinct values of `loc_id`. And you are going to achieve that by adding a GROUP BY clause.

We could easily get a "count" of all rows in employees related to each `loc_id` using an aggregate, `COUNT(*)`.  But you are interested in getting a count of only employees that meet particular criteria... conditional aggregation.

If the combination of `(loc_id,pos)` is UNIQUE in the lookup table. (The example data makes it look like it is, but we can't determine that by the absence of a counterexample in the limited example data)...

If that's unique, we could perform a JOIN operation to that table, to "lookup" the `lbl` associated with the `(loc_id,pos)` for each employee.

```
 SELECT e.loc_id
      , e.pos
      , e.loc
      , l.lbl
   FROM employee e
   LEFT
   JOIN lookup l
     ON l.loc_id = e.loc_id
    AND l.pos    = e.pos
```

If I wanted a count of the number of employees at a given location that were associated with a row in `lookup` with a `lbl` value of `Staff Site 1`, I would tend to write that as...

```
 SELECT e.loc_id
      , SUM(CASE WHEN l.lbl = 'Staff Site 1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Staff Site 1]
   FROM employee e
   LEFT
   JOIN lookup l
     ON l.loc_id = e.loc_id
    AND l.pos    = e.pos
  GROUP BY e.loc_id
  ORDER BY e.loc_id
```

If I wanted a second column, for a count of 'Staff Site 2'

```
 SELECT e.loc_id
      , SUM(CASE WHEN l.lbl = 'Staff Site 1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Staff Site 1]
      , SUM(CASE WHEN l.lbl = 'Staff Site 2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Staff Site 2]
   FROM employee e
   LEFT
   JOIN lookup l
     ON l.loc_id = e.loc_id
    AND l.pos    = e.pos
  GROUP BY e.loc_id
  ORDER BY e.loc_id
```

If I didn't have a specific need to "pivot" that result, I could much more simply run a query that returns separate rows, for every value of `lbl` for every `employee` at a given `loc_id`.

```
 SELECT e.loc_id  AS loc_id
      , e.lbl     AS lbl 
      , SUM(1)    AS cnt
   FROM employee e
   LEFT
   JOIN lookup l
     ON l.loc_id = e.loc_id
    AND l.pos    = e.pos
  GROUP BY e.loc_id
  ORDER BY e.loc_id
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough explanation and breakdown.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this (assuming you really need to do this) is to just put the aggregation in an outer query, wrapped around the conditional stuff (i.e. the subqueries), like this:

```
select key_id, sum(staff_site_1) as staff_site_1, , sum(staff_site_2) as staff_site_2
from (
    SELECT
    employees.key_id
    ,CASE 
        WHEN 
            pos IN (SELECT DISTINCT pos FROM lookup WHERE lbl='Staff') 
        AND 
            loc IN (SELECT DISTINCT loc FROM lookup WHERE lbl='Staff')
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
    END AS staff_site_1
    ,CASE 
        WHEN 
            pos IN (SELECT DISTINCT pos FROM lookup WHERE lbl='Staff') 
        AND 
            loc IN (SELECT DISTINCT loc FROM lookup WHERE lbl='Staff')
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
    END AS staff_site_2
    FROM table 
) x
GROUP BY key_id 
ORDER BY key_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
; with _CTE as (
SELECT
    employees.loc_id
    ,CASE 
            WHEN 
                pos IN (SELECT DISTINCT pos FROM lookup WHERE lbl='Staff') 
            AND 
                loc IN (SELECT DISTINCT loc FROM lookup WHERE lbl='Staff')
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
        END AS StaffSite1
    ,CASE 
            WHEN 
                pos IN (SELECT DISTINCT pos FROM table WHERE lbl='Staff') 
            AND 
                loc IN (SELECT DISTINCT loc FROM table WHERE lbl='Staff')
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
        END AS StaffSite2

FROM table
)
SELECT
    loc_id
    ,SUM(StaffSite1) AS 'Staff Site 1'
    ,SUM(StaffSite2) AS 'Staff Site 2'

FROM _CTE GROUP BY loc_id ORDER BY loc_id
```

**Explanation:** The _CTE is a temporary result set, which here is applying the CASE condition to the data. Then you are running the aggregate function on this result set.

Comment: cte is NOT a temporary table it is an expression.  Think of it as a way of defining a derived table without having all of that extra code in your final select statement.  its a temporary result set that is defined within the execution score of a single SELECT... so it isn't executed when you define it it is executed within regards to the final statement which uses it. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks Matt. I modified my answer to correct the mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere you are gouping with `employees.loc_id` yet it is in the select. Instead you only have `GROUP BY table.key_id ORDER BY key_id`